# How to check if a url is base64 encoded

Tags: java

I'm encoding a string using `Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(str.getBytes())`. How can I check at a later point if the string is `Base64Url Encoded` before I decode it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string is base64 encoded or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703733/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not)

Comment: I saw it but I was wondering if its the same for a url as well

Comment: Chances are that checking if a string is valid base64 or not (and then to follow up with decoding it), is as heavy as just attempting to decode it and then possibly failing it. So just decode it and catch the exception.

Answer (score 2):

When using the Base64 library ([org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64&method=isBase64)) you can use the code below.

```
Base64.isBase64(str)
```

Which returns true/false if the string is a valid Base64 string.